# General construction for category of subobjects

Tags: category-theory

It is well-known that the category of topological pairs is of great use in algebraic topology. Its construction is standard.

Similarly, I just read in Jacobs' "Categorical Logic and Type Theory" about the category of predicates, which is the category of pairs of sets $(X,A)$ where $A \subseteq X$, with morphisms $u: (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ being commutative squares
$$ \begin{array}{ccc}
X &\to &Y \\
\uparrow & & \uparrow \\
A &\to &B.
\end{array} $$

Now clearly these two constructions are almost the same, probably the cases $\mathcal{C} = \mathrm{Top}, \mathrm{Set}$ of a general procedure. It is not something so simple as the arrow category $\mathcal{C}^2$ because of the subobject condition, but it shouldn't be very far. My questions are:

- In what level of generality can we apply this construction?
- What is the procedure in general? (Does it even have a name?)
- Are there other examples that are used in nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The level of generality depends on what properties you want to keep, but the "closest" is arguably the notion of a [subobject fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type+theory#logic_over_type_theory) which only requires $\mathcal{C}$ to have pullbacks (or even just pullbacks along monomorphisms).  It is closely related to the [codomain fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codomain+fibration) (basically it's a codomain fibration restricted to subobjects).  You can then, of course, look at [fibrations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration) (fibered categories) generally.  This and similar constructions are the basis for the notion of [internal logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic) of a category.  The Ingo Blechschmidt [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S8--bIKaWQ) referenced at the bottom of the last page is a nice exposition of taking an internal logic point of view via Kripke-Joyal semantics to algebraic geometry.  Olivia Caramello's [chapters](http://www.oliviacaramello.com/Unification/ToposTheoreticPreliminariesOliviaCaramello.pdf) on topos theory give technical background and examples of this approach.  I assume Bart Jacobs will provide plenty of details and examples as well.  In some sense, these ideas are omni-present; it's just a matter of whether you want to look at things this way.

Comment: Let the OP remark that there is no need for pullbacks to construct the category of subobjects, this is only required if one wants to make $(A\hookrightarrow X) \mapsto X$ a fibration.

Comment: @Pece Good point. Other fibrations can avoid the need for all pullbacks (along monomorphisms) or any pullbacks for that matter. I would be interested if there is an example of the category of subobjects being used in a category that didn't have pullbacks (along monomorphisms).